# Is it possible to fix scarcity of resources?

Tags: civilization-5

Is it possible to adjust or apply a mod to fix the scarcity of resources?  I know that some resources are scarce but sometimes they are too scarce. For example, I tripped around the globe and only got 2 uranium.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When setting up your game, there is an Advanced Setup button that you can press - this allows you to change a large number of more in-depth game settings, including the saturation of Luxury and Strategic Resources.

[image]

The default option is "Standard", with options including "Sparse" (less than Standard), "Abundant" (more than Standard), "Legendary Start" (biased towards fantastic starting positions at the spawn points for all Civs), and "Strategic Balance" (biased towards a fair balance of Strategic resources).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, however, does exist another way to do that?. for example, "unlimited" mines like in starcraft or c&c

Comment: Not outside of any sort of modding, no.